# Spring web app. One war multiple application context

Tags: java, spring, servlets, scheduled-tasks, applicationcontext

I searched for a while but can't manage to find a proper solution to my problem.

I have one WAR web application and I want 2 spring applications running in it one for the web-part, one running scheduled task.
Both applications share a lot of beans so I would like that those two applications share some beans instance.

I'd like to split my contexts in:

-shared-context.xml

-web-context.xml

-task-context.xml

Web-context and task-context must be isolated and not see each other. They need to create a few beans that are the same but have different configs.

Is this possible? And how should I do it?

I tried first to put `<import resource="classpath:shared-context.xml" />` in both web-context and task context and to configure my web.xml as

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>web-context.xml task-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

but the problem is that there is no isolation between web and task. They all share all the beans even the one defined in web-context.xml and task-context.xml

For info here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-context.xml /WEB-INF/task-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.gwtrpcspring.RemoteServiceDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>contentDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ch.olator.servlet.MyContentDownloadServlet</servlet-class> 
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.rpc</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>contentDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/download</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    ... some irrelevant filters ...

</web-app>
```

**UPDATED** 
-To make things clearer I need this isolation between task and web because the task-context which is used to run scheduled task to define some beans that are in web-context but differently. E.g. I have scoped-session beans that are in web-context but I need to define them differently for the tasks as scheduled task can't use scoped-session beans.

Comment: What is the part that is missing from you web.xml? Also you still have a single application, how many xml files or contexts doesn't matter. Generally speaking you already should have 2 contexts, one from the `ContextLoaderListener` and another from the `DispatcherServlet`. The one from the `ContextLoaderListener` functions as a parent for the one from the `DispathcerServlet`. In your posted web.xml you only have a single context the one from the `ContextLoaderListener`, how many xml files you have doesn't matter.

Comment: The missing part are some irrelevent servlet filter. I don't have other context file I used to put everything in the same web-context.xml (maybe it is not the proper way)
Although I want both dispatcher servlet and contentDownloadServlet to share all the beans. I don't want to have isolated and different context between dispatcher servlet and contentDownloadServlet

Comment: Ok. But you only have a single context, no matter how many xml files you have. So what you want should already be the case... Your file isn't loaded twice, it might be parsed twice but that is something different. The beans are the same.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are rigth but I updated my question as it still doesn't do what I'd like

Comment: There will never be a seperation as there is just a single `ApplicationContext`. Why do you so desperatly want to separate the two? Seems to me you are only trying to add complexity...

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am also looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the import tag

in web-context.xml:

> ```
> <import resource="classpath:shared-context.xml" />
> <import resource="classpath:task-context.xml" />
> ```

Comment: No I want that web and task to be separated application I don't want web-context to see beans that are defined in task-context neither task-context to see beans defined in web-context